# Allow application user to submit bugs to TFS 2008

Tags: tfs, workitem

I'm currently trying to find out if there is a way to allow our nightly build application users to submit bug items to TFS.  Everything is developed and used within our private network so there aren't any security issues of that nature that I am aware of.  I don't necessarily need them to be able to assign the bug specifics, but give a title and a description.  It could be equally valuable if users can submit to an issue tracking page on the TFS Project Site.

**Application Language:** C#

**Possible Workflow:**

- User encounters an issue while using the application
- User click feedback button that is only shown in the nightly build
- User fills form detailing issue
- User clicks submit
- Information including user's name is sent to the TFS server and a new bug item is created
- Developers receive a notification (using tfs reporting) and assigns bug appropriately
- Developer contacts user to elaborate on the issue
- Developer fixes bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existing work items, along with the work item web access feature (WIWA) to allow them to enter the bugs.  I believe there isn't a license requirement for them to enter and view their own work items.

WIWA is (default) located at:  `http://tfs:8090/wiwa`

Comment: I do not believe that we have installed the proper stuff (or it is blocked) for wiwa to work.  One thing I did notice is if I went to the url :8090 that I got the Team System Web Access.  This may provide the functionality that we are looking for.